# Key substitution in python

Tags: python

I have two text files, one we'll call `keys` and it looks something like this:

```
S-84
S-72
S-73
S-83
32
S-73
S-83
32
S-65
32
S-84
S-69
S-83
S-84
S-49
```

The other file is sort of a dictionary of key-value pairs:

```
S-49 : "!"
S-65 : "a"
S-66 : "b"
S-67 : "c"
S-68 : "d"
S-69 : "e"
S-70 : "f"
S-71 : "g"
S-72 : "h"
S-73 : "i"
S-74 : "j"
S-75 : "k"
S-76 : "l"
S-77 : "m"
S-78 : "n"
S-79 : "o"
S-80 : "p"
S-81 : "q"
S-82 : "r"
S-83 : "s"
S-84 : "t"
S-85 : "u"
S-86 : "v"
S-87 : "w"
S-88 : "x"
S-89 : "y"
S-90 : "z"
32 : " "
```

I want to read in the first file and replace the keys therein with their values in the second file so that the output file looks like this:

```
this is a test!
```

I don't really know where to start with this.
I was trying to start with something like this manually, but my output is `bleh`

```
with open('newkey.log', 'r') as input_file, open('newkey.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        if line.strip() == 'S-84':
            output_file.write('t\n')
        else:
            output_file.write('bleh\n')
```

I think I am going to have to read-in the second file as a dictionary as well, or I could hard-code it in? I would prefer to end up being able to change that file outside of the interpreter.

Comment: Once you have found an answer to your problem, please click the tick next to that answer to accept it. This lets others with your problem know which solution worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you must first read in the second file to create your dictionary.

```
import re

d['S-186'] = ':'  # To account for the delimiter per your comments below.
with open(key_values_filename, 'r') as f:
    for row in f:
        k, v = row.split(':')
        d[k.strip()] = re.sub('^"|"$', '', v.strip())
```

Then read the other file and get the value from the matched key.

```
missing_value = 'key missing'
with open(keys_filename, 'r') as fin, open(result_filename, 'w') as fout:
    for row in fin:
        fout.write(d.get(row.strip(), missing_value))
```

For an explanation of the regular expression `re.sub('^"|"$', '', v.strip())`, it removes double quotations found either at the start or end of each parsed string stripped of whitespace.

- `^"` asserts position of the quotation at the *start* of the string.
- `"$` asserts position of the quotation at the *end* of the string.
- `|` matches either assertion above.

The above solution works on your sample data.

Comment: I get and error:
'NameError: name 're' is not defined`

Comment: So I used `import re`, but I get another error now:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./try_parse.py", line 7, in <module>
    k, v = row.split(':')
ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: That means there is more than one `:` on a given row.  Have you confirmed *exactly* what that data looks like?

Comment: Yes! That was it! The actual dictionary file is a lot longer than I put here and one of the values was for a colon. I found it and deleted it, and it worked! But now, how do I account for that missing colon?

Comment: Change `d = {}` to  `d['S-186'] = ':'`

Comment: Yeah, just adding it in after the with loop worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re

keys = {a:b for a, b in [re.split("\s:\s", i.strip('\n')) for i in open('second_file.txt')]}

final_message = ''.join(keys[i] for i in [b.strip('\n') for b in open('first_file.txt')])
```